# How to convert user input into MySQL date format?

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

In my Ruby on Rails 4 app I need to convert user entered `dates` like...

```
25.07.2014
25/07/2014
```

...possibly even...

```
25-07-2014
```

...into a the default Date format that can be stored in MySQL database.

```
2014-07-25
```

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strftime: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime

```
date = Time.parse(params[:date])
date.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub) or `String#sub!`, `gsub` or `gsub!`:

```
'25.07.2014'.sub(/(\d{2})\D(\d{2})\D(\d{4})/, '\3-\2-\1')
# => "2014-07-25"
'25/07/2014'.sub(/(\d{2})\D(\d{2})\D(\d{4})/, '\3-\2-\1')
# => "2014-07-25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Time.parse`, Luke. It covers all your examples.

```
>> require 'time'
=> true
>> Time.parse '25.07.2014'
=> 2014-07-25 00:00:00 +0200
>> Time.parse '25/07/2014'
=> 2014-07-25 00:00:00 +0200
>> Time.parse '25-07-2014'
=> 2014-07-25 00:00:00 +0200
>> Time.parse '2014-07-25'
=> 2014-07-25 00:00:00 +0200
```

More in the article [Ruby for Admins: Date and Time](http://rubyforadmins.com/date-and-time#parsing-datetime-from-the-string)